# HAProxy on App Servers for redundant load balancers

Tags: php, mysql, haproxy

I have HAProxy running on a separate server to load balance 2 MySQL servers running master-master / active-passive mode.  However, I now have a single point of failure with the HAProxy load balancer.  I have read that I can use keepalived and spin up another instance of HAProxy.

However, I would like to keep my server costs low and was wondering if I can instead move HAProxy onto my application servers since I already have multiple App servers running behind a separate load balancer.

Is there a way to run HAProxy in the manner?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized this should be on ServerFault instead, not StackOverflow - closing.